# Coverting FLAC audio file into wav Audio file In android

Tags: android, audio

I am able to convert the .amr file to the .wav file by adding the required header info to the newly created file i.e. example.wav file, but unable to convert the .flac file to .wav file properly however I get the .wav file which plays for  the same time for which it was recorded but plays the noise sound as bad Channel signal on Radio instead of recorded voice. Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both the files have been written data in different format so only copying the headers is not the solution, you will have to do proper decoding from flac to pcm and then will have to add headers and store the bytes from pcm to wav file.

Comment: appreciate your efforts, but why  you have not completed the task in SP yet. So do your report with source code this evening.